# Need to check text at specific URL and return result in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that has a bunch of URLs in column A. Let's say A1 is http://google.com, and I want to check if it contains text "Contact Us", and return me a Boolean string if it is. For example 1 if it has "contact us" and 0 if it does not. I know this would have to be javascript code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use `indexOf("contact us")` on the javascript accessible variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But still not sure how to write it to actually check the content of the URL and not just a given "text".

Comment: If you are referring to content of the webpage that url will serve, you would have to fetch and index the content of it. I dont think its possible without complex environment.